# Backgroundworker freezing when coming against .visible properties

Tags: vb.net, winforms, backgroundworker, visible

I am experiencing my UI hanging whenever I am trying to set the visibility of a control depending on logic to visible = true or visibile = false it hangs.  I could set everything on my form to True in the designer and not have any issues with the backgroundworker handling the logic i put inside it however whenever I have to switch from visible true/false it hangs the application.  Is this due to some cross threading occuring where I'm trying to set the visibility on the UI anywhere else but the UI thread?  If so, why am I able to change the text properties of my controls and not have any issues but visible is giving me some issue?

Comment: Background threads are not meant to have any knowledge of the UI.

Comment: I've been looking around and have been seeing people who use the bgw to help quicken the process of showing UI

Comment: Does not make it right. What are you trying to speed up?

Comment: The UI I use has 50+ controls on it and logic for each control(data, visible, enable, etc) and was hoping to process the controls with lots of logic(main thread) against the smaller-type controls with logic(bgw) to quicken the loading process of the window.  What took 6 seconds to load is now taking 2 but would like to make sure it's the right way and find out the issue with the visible property

Comment: You need to use a delegate to modify any control on the UI thread from a backgroundworker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are crashing due to executing UI commands on a background thread. You can perform whatever non-UI logic you're doing on that thread, and then change the actual value of .visible or other UI controls by using the dispatcher - see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: That makes sense.  May i ask why I am able to modify the .text property of the labels on the form without having any freezing?  Only when trying to modify a few select proprties(enabled, visible, etc) it is freezing.